# IntelliJ IDEA: Kotlin missing

Tags: intellij-idea, installation, kotlin

I went to Linux Mint 18 from MacOS, first Timer on Linux.
Now I wanted to install Kotlin.

Downloaded it from here: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html#section=linux

Used this install instruction: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2jSX6lcFElE
(download IntelliJ from Jetbrains and put it in home-folder)

Now that I wanted to start a new Kotlin project, it seems missing:
No Kotlin in IntelliJ IDEA:
[image: No Kotlin in IntelliJ IDEA]

What have I missed out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be a problem with the Kotlin language plugin when updating to IntelliJ 18.1

Try to reinstall the corresponding plugin. I was able to fix it this way.

Comment: In my case, I simply needed to update the Kotlin plugin. From the preferences screen, locate the plugins section, and switch to the "installed" tab. In that list, the Kotlin plugin was showing that an update was available. Updating and restarting the IDE resolved the problem.